# Error with referenced before assignment in python

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to create a login and register program in simple console python, however when trying to make a loop that will check if the username contains a digit I keep getting the error, ("UnboundLocalError: local variable 'includesDigit' referenced before assignment") the code is:

```
def register():
   incluesDigit = False
   print("")
   print("Create Account")
   print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
   print("Username: ")
   registerUsername = input("")

   for char in registerUsername:
       if char.isdigit():
           includesDigit = True

   if includesDigit == True:
       print("Please enter a username that does not contain a number")
       register()

   print("Password: ")
   registerPassword = input("")
   if len(registerPassword) < 5:
       print("Please enter a password that is atleast 5 characters")
       register()
   if len(registerPassword) > 15:
       print("Please enter a password that is less than or fifteen character")
   logCreate = open("C:\\Desktop\\Login Program\\Accounts\\" + registerUsername + ".txt", "w")
   logCreate.write(registerPassword)
   logCreate.close()
   login()
```

Comment: pls fix your indentations with this code, see this [link](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php) for reference.

Comment: Why the `== True` in `if includesDigit == True:` ? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, and you should use a context manager to handle `log_create`.

Comment: "incluesDigit" isn't the same name as "includesDigit" -- the first one doesn't have a 'd' in it.  The first one is set at the start of the function, and the second is used if the if statement.  Also, please include a more complete error message when asking for help, like the line number that it references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in line 2.

```py
incluesDigit = False
```

Should be

```py
includesDigit = False
```

Comment: You should mark this as the answer if it helped you @Rabzy

Comment: I was going to, but it said I had to wait